# Comparing two hyperbolic structures on a surface

Tags: cv.complex-variables

Let S be a compact hyperbolic surface (a compact riemann surface of genus ≥2). Let S′=S∖P where P⊂S is a finite subset of points. Then S′ is hyperbolic too.

Question: how is related the hyperbolic structure of S′ to the one of S?

Of course, I think that this is well-known. A good reference would be welcome!

Thanks

Comment: There is no good relation between the two hyperbolic structures, it is not even clear what to conjecture here, since these structures live in different moduli spaces. One thing is that the structure on the noncompact surface will depend on the location of the set $P$.

Comment: Your question is unclear. What do you mean by "how related"? One clearly determines another. In a very complicated way. What exactly do you want to know?

Answer (score 5):

By the [Schwarz lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_lemma), the lengths of paths on $S'$ will be strictly greater than the lengths of corresponding paths on $S$.

Comment: It is possible to estimate how much bigger the metric is on $S'$ than $S$ near the punctures. See section 2.11 in McMullen's "Complex Dynamics and Renormalization" book.